How to assess the accuracy of an algorithm on a massive set of samples?
I have a set of samples with $64^{64}$ elements. For simplicity I'll bring the following example: we have a set of $64^{64}$ numbers. If we consider each number as a question then all of them have associated to them a unique answer ($64^{64}$ possible answers in total). We have an algorithm that when given a number it needs to compute the associated answer. The algorithm returns true if it correctly computed the answer, otherwise it returns false. The algorithm doesn't use statistics to compute an answer and it doesn't try to guess an answer. It's just capable of computing some answers and incapable of computing some others. In the ideal case the algorithm should return true for every number. The objective is to assess the accuracy of the algorithm with some certainty. The desired outcome should be being able to find a probable lower bound for the accuracy of the algorithm. The problem is that it can't be tested on every single sample, so we need to test it on a big enough subset instead. So for example, now I'm picking $10^6$ random samples and testing the algorithm on them. But $10^6$ is a tiny number next to $64^{64}$. So I wonder how big the subset should be to be able to assess the accuracy of the algorithm with some certainty.
Unfortunately, I don't enough knowledge in statistics to answer this question. So at least some directions would be very appreciated!

What kind of answer are you looking for? What kind of expectations do you have for the accuracy of the algorithm a priori? In many cases, it doesn't turn out to matter very much how large the overall population is ($64^{64}$ here, which is a $58$-digit number—do you really have a sample this large?). For example, the sample size needed for polls to determine a proportion within a $95$-percent error margin of (say) $3$ percent is maybe $1200$ or so, whether the overall population is a U.S. state or the whole U.S.

@BrianTung even a 1-5% accuracy would be significant. the context is that I'm trying to implement an attack on a cryptographic method, so I'm trying to assess whether I can crack a significant number of messages.

Incidentally, it would be good to know mostly whether you expect the percentage to be close to either $0$ or $100$, or somewhere in the middle. In the latter case, the distribution is likely to look normal-ish, as long as the sample is sizable, but that is often misleading in the former case.

@BrianTung okay thanks, it's the latter - the higher the better.

Assuming that your $10^6$ samples are indeed random or close enough to random, then the proportion "true" seen in the sample is likely to be close to the population proportion "true", for example  within $0.001$ of the population proportion with at least $95%$ probability and more accurate than that if the sample proportion is close to $0$ or $1$.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval discusses various ways of constricting a confidence interval
